# Multiples foreach recursively or RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, spl

I am using this code, that works well. However seems like not the best option due the multiples foreach.

```
foreach ($arr_items as $key => $value) {
    $id_user = $key;
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $x => $y) {
            $id_transacao = $y['id_transacao'];
            $id_duplicated = $y['id_duplicated'];
            foreach ($y as $g => $b) {
                if (is_array($b)){
                    foreach ($b as $kn => $l) {
                        var_dump($id_user);
                        var_dump($id_transacao);
                        var_dump($id_duplicated);
                        var_dump($l);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code will outputs a bunch of results, probably fast, but totally disordered.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr_items));

}
```

My question is: It's ok if I use first code, or should I try something with the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. My problem is that will be difficult to generate the exactly same structure in the second option.
Anyway, any optimization will be nice.

Comment: What do you means by 'totally disordered' ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet basically the results are presented sequentially at the same level. so, I will loose the  depth reference, I think.

Comment: You are actually attempting to *traverse* a tree. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) lists and explains the types of possible traversal orders. You should read that article in order to be able to explain more specifically what you expect.

Comment: can you post `$arr_items`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the other constants for the `mode` parameter on `RecursiveIteratorIterator::__construct`? The default is `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY`.

From the [Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php)

```
RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY - The default. Lists only leaves in iteration.
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST - Lists leaves and parents in iteration with parents coming first.
RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST - Lists leaves and parents in iteration with leaves coming first.
```

Maybe `SELF_FIRST` is what you need.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr_items), 
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`inside the foreach loop, you can use the `$filter->getDepth()` function to separate the child, self, and grandchild.

You can also set `$filter->setMaxDepth(int $depth);`.